# Elasticsearch on cloudfoundary

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy my asp.net core 2.2 application using buildpacks on SCP cloudfoundary. My application has dependency on elasticsearch. How can I assembly my buildpack file so that I can install both my dotnet core 2.2. app along with Elasticsearch running as a service.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would want to run Elasticsearch as an app on Cloud Foundry because it would be difficult to persist any data. The file system your app gets on CF is ephemeral, and is scoped to the lifetime of your app instance. Thus if your app restarts anything you've written to disk is gone. If that doesn't matter to you, I suppose you could proceed.

That said, you wouldn't want to run it as part of the same app. You'd want to push them separately as two different apps. That way you can scale them separately, if one crashes, you don't lose both, and you have dedicated memory limits for each app (i.e. one of the two, cannot consume more than it's share of memory and crash the app).

Having said all that, my suggestion would be to run `cf marketplace` and see if there is a Elasticsearch service in your Marketplace. That would be the easiest way forward. You could simply `cf create-service` and make your Elasticsearch service.

If there isn't one in your marketplace, then you can look at getting one through AWS/GCP/Azure or some other provider. Then you can create a service instance in CF with `cf cups` (it's called a user-provided service). You can bind this user-provided service to your app just like a service created through the marketplace.

If all else fails and you can't find a service from a provider you trust, you could always run your own. Then use a user-provided service to pass in creds.